# Why does Google provide a client secret for a Native application?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm writing a native application that works against a Google API. Upon registering my application, and despite its explicit designation as Native, the Google Developers Console provides me with a client secret.

As far as I understand the OAuth 2.0 protocol, native apps should never have a client secret, since they cannot guarantee its secrecy. Is Google mistaken in its implementation of OAuth 2.0?  How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the client secret isn't terribly useful in a native application from a being kept secret perspective.  I suspect it's there mainly for consistency with the web application flow.

It does however have at least 1 useful feature...  the original developer can reset it at any time, effectively revoking all refresh tokens bound to that client ID.

Comment: This is my first time working with OAuth so I'm not sure what the security implications are of embedding the client secret in the application. Once I do that, I'm revealing it to the world, and it can be reverse-engineered. How concerned should I be about that?  How much of an attack vector does knowing the client secret give a potential attacker?

Comment: To get an access token (which is what you ultimately use to access an API) in a native application you need to supply Google with a refresh token (this is what Google provides at the end of the original OAuth dance - and your app typically stores for the user) and your client secret.  It is fine to bake this into your application (know it can be reverse engineered) - on it's own it doesn't give access to any data - it is always used with a refresh token.